# how manage users and groups to share data between multiple containers?

Tags: php, apache, docker, ftp

We are trying to consolidate some old undocumented PHP web apps. To make the apps portable between environments we have containerized them. We are not supposed to change the code, except for some configuration files.

We have used a custom `php-5.4-apache` container that mounts a host folder into `/var/www/html` to serve the web apps. The apache server runs as `www-data` user. The `entrypoint` is configured to set the correct folder and file permissions on the `/var/www/html` folder and changing the ownership to `www-data`.

One of the web apps uploads images through Http and then moves it to other folder using Ftp and `someUser` credentials. This requires us to have an additional container running the Ftp server.

The problem is that files are correctly uploaded but then they can't be moved around using Ftp. There seems to be a problem with permissions.

Our assumption is that if the Ftp server and the Http server where to be hosted under the same machine, we should have the `www-data` and `someUser` users under the same group `someGroup`. And that the `/var/www/html` contents should be owned by `anyUser:someGroup`.

How can we achieve this when Ftp and Http servers are running in different containers and the data is mounted from the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying UID and GID on the files carries across from host to container so you just need to match the ID numbers when setting up users or groups anywhere. The name of the user/group doesn't actually have any impact, except maybe on your sanity.

In this case you would need to make sure the group is available in both containers with the same GID and the files are created group writable.

```
 addgroup --gid 5001 somegroup
 adduser --disabled-password --uid 5001 --gid 5001 someuser
```

If you want to confuse someone in the future, you could even use the same UID in each container for different user names.

Web `adduser --disabled-password --uid 5001 www-data`
FTP `adduser --disabled-password --uid 5001 someUser`

Then both users could read and write the same files on the shared volume as the UID's match, but this is probably not a particularly obvious solution.